# Why won't my factor column value change to a date value?

Tags: date

I know this is elementary but I can't seem to figure it out, even after reading other posts.

In a dataset, I want to convert an entire column into a date. The current class is factor.

The value in the field looks like this `12/25/2012`

This is what I've tried.

```
 C$DateofDeath=as.Date(C$DateofDeath,'%m/%d/%Y')
Error in as.Date.default(C$DateofDeath, "%m/%d/%Y") : 
  do not know how to convert 'C$DateofDeath' to class “Date”

 C$DateofDeath=as.Date(C$DateofDeath,"%m/%d/%Y")
Error in as.Date.default(C$DateofDeath, "%m/%d/%Y") : 
  do not know how to convert 'C$DateofDeath' to class “Date” 

Claims$DateofDeath=strptime(as.character(Claims$DateofDeath),format= '%m/%d/%Y')
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "DateofDeath", value = list(sec = numeric(0),  : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 71616

Claims$DateofDeath=strptime(as.character(Claims$DateofDeath),format= "%m/%d/%Y")
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "DateofDeath", value = list(sec = numeric(0),  : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 71616
```

Comment: You should add a language tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use as.POSIXct

C$DateOfDeath<-as.POSIXct(as.character(C$DateOfDeath), format = "%d/%m/%Y")

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of R experts here but you have to specify `R` as one of your tags to get them to notice your question.

Looks like you have tried a bunch of combinations but not the right one.

```
> C <- data.frame(DateofDeath="12/25/2012",other=TRUE)
> as.Date(as.character(C$DateofDeath),format="%m/%d/%Y")
[1] "2012-12-25"
```

Notice that `as.Date()` takes a character input, not a factor.  So you need to convert to character, then to Date.

Your `strptime()` versions seem fine to me except that you call are referring to the dataframe `Claims` instead of `C`.  Actually `strptime()` should convert the factor to character for you, so you don't need the `as.character()` part with those.